# ASP.NET Core Disable Response Buffering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm attempting to stream a large JSON file built on the fly to a client (could be 500 MB+). I'm trying to disable response buffering for a variety of reasons, though mostly for memory efficiency.

I've tried writing directly to the `HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter` but the response seems to be buffered in memory before writing to the output. The return type of this method is `Task`.

```
HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
HttpContext.Response.ContentLength = null;
await HttpContext.Response.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
var bodyStream = HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter.AsStream(true);
await bodyStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("["), cancellationToken);
await foreach (var item in cursor.WithCancellation(cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    await bodyStream.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.SerializeToUtf8Bytes(item, DefaultSettings.JsonSerializerOptions), cancellationToken);
    await bodyStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(","), cancellationToken);
    
    await bodyStream.FlushAsync(cancellationToken);
    await Task.Delay(100,cancellationToken);
}
await bodyStream.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("]"), cancellationToken);
bodyStream.Close();
await HttpContext.Response.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

*Note: I realize this code is very hacky, trying to make it work, then clean it up*

I'm using the `Task.Delay` to verify the response is not being buffered when testing locally as I do not have full production data. I have also tried `IAsyncEnumerable` and `yield return`, but that fails because the response is so large that Kestrel thinks the enumerable is infinite.

I've tried

1. Setting [KestrelServerLimits.MaxResponseBufferSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.kestrelserverlimits.maxresponsebuffersize?view=aspnetcore-1.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_KestrelServerLimits_MaxResponseBufferSize) to a small number, even 0;
2. Writing with `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync`
3. Writing with `HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter.AsStream()`
4. Writing with a pipe writer patter and `HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter`
5. Removing all middleware
6. Removing calls to `IApplicationBuilder.UseResponseCompression`

### Update

7. Tried disabling response buffering before setting the `ContentType` (so before any writes to the response) with no effect

```
var responseBufferingFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
responseBufferingFeature?.DisableBuffering();
```

### Updated Sample Code

This reproduces the issue quite simply. The client doesn't receive any data until `response.CompleteAsync()` is called.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("stream")]
public async Task<EmptyResult> FileStream(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = DisableResponseBuffering(HttpContext);
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/gzip");
    HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename=\"player-data.csv.gz\"");
    await response.StartAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var memory = response.Writer.GetMemory(1024*1024*10);
    response.Writer.Advance(1024*1024*10);
    await response.Writer.FlushAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await Task.Delay(5000).ConfigureAwait(false);
    var str2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Bar!\r\n");
    memory = response.Writer.GetMemory(str2.Length);
    str2.CopyTo(memory);
    response.Writer.Advance(str2.Length);
    await response.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return new EmptyResult();
}

private IHttpResponseBodyFeature DisableResponseBuffering(HttpContext context)
{
    var responseBufferingFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
    responseBufferingFeature?.DisableBuffering();
    return responseBufferingFeature;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working when using http.sys (with ASP.NET Core 6):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.WebHost.UseHttpSys();
        var app = builder.Build();
        app.MapGet("/", async (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 201;
            await context.Response.StartAsync();
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("x"); // client gets status code after this line
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable buffering on response futures:

```
HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>().DisableBuffering()
//As mentioned in documentation, to take effect, call it before any writes
```

And use `BodyWriter` in `Utf8JsonWriter` for more efficiency:

```
 var pipe = context.HttpContext.Response.BodyWriter;
 await pipe.WriteAsync(startArray);
 using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(pipe,
            new JsonWriterOptions
            {
                Indented = option.WriteIndented,
                Encoder = option.Encoder,
                SkipValidation = true
            }))
 {
      var dotSet = false;
      foreach (var item in enumerable)
      {
           if (dotSet)
               await pipe.WriteAsync(dot);
           JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, itemType, option);
           await pipe.FlushAsync();
           writer.Reset();
           dotSet = true;
      }
 }
 await pipe.WriteAsync(endArray);
```

In my case it give results: total memory allocation become greater over 80% compared to newcoreapp2.2 after first requests, but no more memory leaks.

Comment: Updated, no dice

Comment: I have same trouble, with any large JSON, and yes my answer is not a solution, just workaround to avoid 'OutOfMemory'.

Comment: Could you help me with my question, I've tried DisableBuffering but I still get the OutOfMemory exception: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74828066/14664018

Answer (score 1):

For those who is still interested this code sends data right away when using curl:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var g = context.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();
    g.DisableBuffering(); // doesn't seem to make a difference

    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    //context.Response.ContentLength = null;

    await g.StartAsync();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        var line = $"this is line {i}\r\n";
        var bytes = utf8.GetBytes(line);
        // it seems context.Response.Body.WriteAsync() and
        // context.Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync() work exactly the same
        await g.Writer.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(bytes));
        await g.Writer.FlushAsync();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    await g.CompleteAsync();
}
```

Variations I tried with and without `DisableBufering()` as well as writing to a pipe (`IHttpResponseBodyFeature.Writer` vs `HttpContext.Response.Body`) didn't seem to make a difference.

In curl it shows messages right away, however in Chrome and some rest clients it waits for the whole stream to show up.

So I would recommend testing your code behavior with a client that doesn't wait for the whole stream to present it. Another option I am still checking if aspnet core automatically picks up compression possibility if client asks for it even though compression is not configured in the pipeline.
So I would recomm