# ASP.NET Core API - Returning large data causes System.OutOfMemoryException - Do I need to use a stream?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return large amounts of data from a Web API without pagination in this controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFilteredLocations([FromBody] LocationReportQueryDto locationReportQuery, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var result = await locationReportDataAccess.GetFilteredLocationsAsync(locationReportQuery, token);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

results count can be 277,000+ items.

Client side:

```
public async Task<List<LocationDto>> GetFilteredLocationsAsync(LocationReportQueryDto locationReportQuery, CancellationToken token = default)
{
    var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Data");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/reports/GetFilteredLocations", locationReportQuery, token);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var list = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<LocationDto>>(cancellationToken: token);
    if (list == null) throw new HttpRequestException("HTTP Call - Response is null");
    return list;
}
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
[2022-12-16T17:27:41.154Z] Error: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.EnsureCapacity(Int32 value)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LimitMemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsyncCore(Task serializeToStreamTask, MemoryStream tempBuffer)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
at...
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
log @ blazor.server.js:1
```

In my case I can't use pagination because of the legacy database I'm using, which doesn't allow querying chunks of data, so do I have to return a stream for such large data?

Comment: You might be able to try https://blog.elmah.io/stream-large-content-from-asp-net-core-to-avoid-outofmemoryexception/ but something tells me this isn't best practice.

Comment: How would I implement that in my code, I would need to yield return the results list?

Comment: I _think_ you'd place it in `GetFilteredLocationsAsync` where your `await response` line is.  You may need to change your return types of that method, maybe to an [`IAsyncEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerable-1?view=net-7.0).  You may also want to read the docs on [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield).

Comment: I yield return the results and it still causes the exception.

Comment: Try to use custom json response filter, and try forcing .net pipe to flush buffer by pipe.FlusAsync on each array element https://github.com/alexandrvslv/datawf/blob/7bb3168b93ec5cba3860292cc2d9d66650840112/DataWF.WebService.Common/Json/DBItemOutputFormatter.cs#L107